# VBA Macro Excecutes more than once

Tags: vba, excel, macros

It's the first time I'm trying some VBA code, so it might be a very noob mistake but I just can't see it, this is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If InRange(ActiveCell, Range("N4:N33")) Then
            If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Text, "EFECTIVO") > 0 Then
                If (Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1))) Then
                    If (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value > 0) Then
                        Cancel = True
                        Call RestaEfectivo
                        Range("F4").Select
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
End Sub
Function InRange(Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range) As Boolean
    InRange = Not (Application.Intersect(Range1, Range2) Is Nothing)
End Function

Sub RestaEfectivo()
    Range("F4").Value = Range("F4").Value - ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
End Sub
```

The idea is that I have a dropdown list on my cells N4 to N33, whenever I choose the option "EFECTIVO" it should take the value to the left of the ActiveCell (N#) and substract its value from the F4 cell. In essence F4 = F4 - N#.

The code does what it's supposed to do, however, it appears to execute 50 times? The original value of my F4 cell is 230, once I execute the code it turns into -20

Any idea where I messed up or if I'm missing some code, validation, etc?

As I said, I'm new to VBA for Excel Macros, so don't worry about pointing out noob mistakes.

Comment: You need to disable events at the beginning and re-enable them at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to toggle the `EnableEvents` property of `Application` at the point where you call your `RestaEfectivo` sub-routine. Notice that during handling the `Worksheet_Change` event you call the `RestaEfectivo` sub-routine which *fires the worksheet change event again* - that is why your macro executes more than once.

You can make the code change like this:

```
Cancel = True

' turn off events to enable changing cell value without a new 'change' event
Application.EnableEvents = False

Call RestaEfectivo

' re-enable events to ensure normal application behaviour
Application.EnableEvents = True

Range("F4").Select
```

### Update

OP asked a follow up question - how to make the range dynamic but ignore the bottom row as this would contain a `SUM` formula.

One possible solution is to check for the change in any cell of column `N`:

```
If InRange(ActiveCell, Range("N:N")) Then
```

And then recode the `InRange` sub - see the code comments for logic and assumptions:

```
Function InRange(Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range) As Boolean

    Dim blnInRange As Boolean
    Dim blnResult As Boolean
    Dim blnCellHasSumFormula As Boolean
    Dim blnCellIsEmpty As Boolean

    'primary check for cell intersect
    blnInRange = Not (Application.Intersect(Range1, Range2) Is Nothing)

    If blnInRange Then
        'follow-up checks
        blnCellIsEmpty = (Range1.Value = vbNullString)
        If blnCellIsEmpty Then
            'cell in range but empty - assume beneath row with SUM
            blnResult = False
        Else
            If Range1.HasFormula Then
                'check for sum formula
                blnCellHasSumFormula = (InStr(1, Range1.Formula, "SUM(", vbTextCompare) > 0)
                If blnCellHasSumFormula Then
                    ' cell in the SUM row
                    blnResult = False
                Else
                    ' cell is in range, not empty and not a SUM formula
                    blnResult = True
                End If
            Else
                'assume non-empty cell without formula is good
                blnResult = True
            End If
        End If
    Else
        blnResult = False
    End If

    'return to event handler
    InRange = blnResult

End Function
```

Comment: It works! That is exactly what I was missing. I had no idea that the Macro would fire the event again.

Comment: Quick additional question, as you can see in my code, I check if the ActiveCell is in the N4:N33 range, what if I create a table and then add a few more rows? How could I make my Macro keep working? I can't select the whole column cause I have a SUM function at the end of it.

Comment: Maybe you could use the entire column, but update the `InRange` function to check if the cell contains a `SUM` function and return `False`?

Comment: Explaining and then illustrating changes in the code is a good approach.